# How many different 13-digit numbers ​​can you get if you write down all the numbers from 1 to 11 , one behind the other in all possible orders?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> How many different 13-digit numbers ​​can you get if you write down
>   all the numbers from 1 to 11, one behind the other in all possible
>   orders ?

This is one of the questions in final exam when everybody has hard time. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrange $11$ numbers in $11!$ ways. You have to subtract the half the cases of $1$ beside $11$ because, both ways it is $111$. That is, subtract $\frac {10!}2$

The answer - $$11! - \frac {10!}2$$

Comment: thank you, kind sir. but what about "0" from "10"?

Comment: @Ivan Everytime 0 comes, The $1$ before it will always be $10$. So, there is no problem. There can't be $ 1$ $10$ or $11$ $0$ . Like in the case of $11$ $1$ or $1$ $11$

Comment: Oh, i see now. One last question, about this 10!, why is there 10!, but not 11!?

Comment: @Ivan It is beacuse I am grouping $11$ and $1$ together. When I group, I now have only $10$ elements- $9$ numbers and $1$ group.